# Forced casting to optional inside a generic in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I thought I knew Swift. That was until today. Trying to cast a given value, it all works as expected until I do it with a generic, but not any generic…

```
import Foundation

func castA<T, U>(value: U) -> T {
    return value as! T
}

func castB<T>(value: AnyObject?) -> T {
    return value as! T
}

typealias Foo = String?

let bar: AnyObject? = "foo"
let baz: AnyObject? = nil

print(bar as! String?) // Optional("foo")
print(baz as! String?) // nil

print(bar as! Foo) // Optional("foo")
print(baz as! Foo) // nil

print(castA(bar) as String?) // Optional("foo")
print(castA(baz) as String?) // nil

print(castB(bar) as String?) // Optional("foo")
print(castB(baz) as String?) // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The trick with specifying both types works in `castA`, but nearly identical `castB` fails with the same input. I want to know what's going on and if it's possible to make `castB` example work. I need this in Swift 2.2, but information if this has changed in Swift 3 is welcome.

Comment: An optional init parameter but a non-optional property is a contradiction – as well as `as! String?`–  and with the forced unwrapping an invitation for a runtime error. Either you want (real) optionals to be considered or not. If yes you have to declare the property as optional (`?`). If no declare the init parameter as non-optional.

Comment: Thanks for input. What do you mean by (real) optionals? I pass the exact type I want to work with in `Bar<String?>`, it is `Optional<String>` and that's what the property type is – does it get any more real optional than that? If question isn't clear, please consider saying what isn't exactly. I'd really love to know the answer.

Comment: A *real* optional is for example `String?`. Again, either use `let value: T?` or `init(value: AnyObject)` depending on if you want to use optionals or not.

Comment: Stefan, you're fixating on details – they are not the problem. I've updated the example and found a workaround, but the question remains. Hope this is clearer, any thoughts?